# Trouble formatting with 2-dimensional array matrices

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, methods

I need my matrices to look exactly like this.(with numbers lined up under text)

```
 Here are the two matrices, and the result when added: 
    2   2   7   4        3   4   3   3        5   6  10   7
    4   4   8   8        6   8   5   5       10  12  13  13
    1   9   3   7        6   8   6   9        7  17   9  16
    2   3   2   9   +    4   4   7   1   =    6   7   9  10
    2   9   1   1        9   8   2   5       11  17   3   6
    6   1   8   4        4   8   2   2       10   9  10   6
```

The results I am currently getting look like.

```
Here are the two matrices, and the result when added:
   8   5   6   6        3   8   2   3       11  13   8   9
   7   7   4   5        4   9   2   1       11  16   6   6
   9   4   4   8        5   1   1   1       14   5   5   9
   4   2   7   7   +    7   9   1   3   =    11  11   8  10
   4   3   5   3        5   6   8   7        9   9  13  10
   4   2   2   1        3   9   5   5        7  11   7   6
```

As you can see the code for the arrays sum is shifted to the right, and I am not quite sure how to fix this.

```
    public static void printResult(int [][]array1, int [][]array2, int[][]sum, char arithmetic)
{
if (arithmetic == '+') {
        // Text for two matrices when added
        System.out.print("Here are the two matrices, and the result when added:\n");

        // For loop to print array1 + array2 = sum with format
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
            // For loop to print out array 1 and add string, if to place +
            for (int j = 0; j < array1[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%4s", array1[i][j]);     
                if (i == array1.length / 2 && j == array1[i].length-1) {
                    System.out.printf("%4s", '+');
                }
            }
            System.out.print("\t");

            // For loop to print out array2 and equals string, if to place =
            for (int j = 0; j < array1[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%2s", array2[i][j] + "   ");
                if (i == array1.length / 2 && j == array1[i].length-1) {
                    System.out.printf("%1s", '=');
                }
            }
            System.out.print("  ");

            // For loop to print out sum of array1 + array2
            for (int j = 0; j < array1[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%4s", sum[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
    else if (arithmetic == '-') {
    }
    else if (arithmetic == '*') {
    }
    else if (arithmetic == '/') {
    }
    else if (arithmetic == '%') {
    }
}
```

Also a 3x3 array when printed out looks like.

```
 Here are the two matrices, and the result when added: 
    2   2   7    3   4   3        5   6   8   
    4   4   8   +        6   8   5   =     7   9  13  
    1   9   3    6   8   6        7   7
```

Comment: Why is this tagged python? That looks like Java to me...

Comment: @MattDMo might of been a mistake and did not notice it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is meant to insure that numbers, when printed, always take up 2 spaces:

```
System.out.printf("%2s", array2[i][j] + "   ");
```

But because of the added (technically, *concatenated*) `"  "`, you get a string that is bigger than the `%2s` field, so there is no padding of short numbers.

Plus, you have code to decide when to print the `+` & `=`, but each should be deciding between printing the symbol and printing a space, to keep everything lined up.